# loading dynamic images into a custom UITableViewCell slows scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am loading some images dynamically into a UITableView and creating some simple custom cells.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I am passing through the content for each cell like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ImagesCell *cell                = (ImagesCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{

    NSUInteger row              = [indexPath row];
    Playlist *playlist          = [[playlistManager playlists] objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *thumbPath         = [(NSString *) playlist.imagePath stringByAppendingString: @"100x75.png"];
    NSArray *nib                = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImagesCell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell                        = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.topLabel.text          = playlist.title;
    cell.bottomLabel.text       = playlist.artistName;
    cell.customImageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: thumbPath]]];
    cell.opaque                 = YES;
    cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
return cell;}
```

I am also changing the height like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CGFloat result;
result = ROW_HEIGHT;
return result;}
```

This all works - in that it loads / shows the content - but when  I test it on the device it paused on each cell redraw slightly, causing pretty rough scrolling.

Can anyone show me how to load the image in a way that would fix this? I have had a look at some asynchronous examples and apples LazyLoading example but this is my first iphone proj and find it a bit tough going.

If anyone has examples or some code to share that would be a great help.

Many thanks

*UPDATE*

The answer selected works but loads all the items in before showing the UITableView.

After much cutting and pasting and version control, the best solution seems to be [MarkJNet's HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache)

This gives image caching as well as asynchronous loading, its very easy to implement (although I havent got it working with a nib yet but I am hopeful it shouldn't be too tough.

Hope that helps someone.

Thanks again to @RedBlueThing and @Marcelo-Alves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do your image loading earlier?

Try adding an image property to the *Playlist* and do the *imageWithData* when you populate the *playlistManager*.

**Update for comment**

So your header for the Playlist object needs to include a UIImage object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@interface Playlist : NSObject 
{ 
    NSURL *imagePath; 
    NSString *title; 
    NSString *subTitle; 
    NSString *mediaType; 
    NSString *artistName; 
    NSInteger id; 

    // Add your image member
    UIImage * image;
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *imagePath; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subTitle; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mediaType; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artistName; 
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger id;

// and a property , make sure you synthesize this in the implementation 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;

@end
```

When you set the imagePath property, you can also create the UIImage.

```
NSString * thumbPath = [(NSString *) self.imagePath stringByAppendingString: @"100x75.png"];

// the property is set as retain, so this will increment our reference count
self.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: thumbPath]]];
```

So you are doing this when you set up the image object (perhaps in the init method), so the processing is done well before the *UITableView* is displayed.

Comment: I will give it a try, I suppose I could limit the list of items to maybe 25 and do a 'load 25 more' cell at the bottom to avoid large loads

Comment: back again, any idea how I would do that, Playlist.h is as follows:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Playlist : NSObject {

 NSURL *imagePath;
 NSString *title;
    NSString *subTitle;
    NSString *mediaType;
    NSString *artistName;
 NSInteger id;
 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *imagePath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mediaType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artistName;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger id;

@end

Comment: @craigk I guess if you decide to go down that path, you might want to look into loading the images async (rather than having more UI for loading additional rows). Good luck :)

Comment: sorry about the mash of code, `code` doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: @RedBlueThing, ok thanks, I take it thats a big change to what is above?

Comment: @RedBlueThing Thanks mate! it worked. Youve been a great help, I really appreciate your patience and effort. I'll update my post to put what I have done, Im sure there is some memory issues in there but I can get to them. Cheers!

Comment: yeah, the preload is too long, will have to look more closely at asynchronous image loading...

Comment: @craigk No problems. Good luck with the async stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to override `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 to change the height, this will really slow down the table scrolling if not doing right. Just change it in IB.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcelo, I tried this already and if I comment out the pverride the cells go back to what looks like a default size, when they scroll off screen and then back on, they slightly change position in the cell. The nib is the same height as ROW_HEIGHT above.

The same stutter on image load occurs even with this commented out. The stutter doesnt occur if I have no image loading or the same image from the library in the cell.

Comment: @craigk This makes sense. Returning ROW_HEIGHT from this message is not going to impact the UITableView performance.

Comment: just in case some is looking if you have a fixed table cell height in your list then just add: self.tableView.rowHeight = 80; in your viewDidLoad method and all will be well

Answer (score 0):

After much cutting and pasting and version control, the best solution seems to be [MarkJNet's HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/)

This gives image caching as well as asynchronous loading, its very easy to implement (although I havent got it working with a nib yet but I am hopeful it shouldn't be too tough.

Hope that helps someone.

Thanks again to @RedBlueThing and @Marcelo-Alves